# Executing a list of PostgreSQL queries returned as result of a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I do have a SELECT ... which returns me a list SQL commands that I want to execute.

I would like to execute these in Postgres, so I do not have to pipe them again.

Here is an example, a SQL query that returns lost of SQL command to be executed for changing the owners. I do want to execute all of them.

```
select 'alter table '|| tablename ||' owner to jira;' from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public'
UNION
select 'alter table '|| sequence_name ||' owner to jira;' from information_schema.sequences            where sequence_schema= 'public'
UNION
select 'alter table '|| table_name ||' owner to jira;' from information_schema.views where       table_schema= 'public';
```

This returns something like:

```
alter table moved_issue_key owner to jira;
alter table jquartz_scheduler_state owner to jira;
alter table AO_60DB71_WORKINGDAYS_ID_seq owner to jira;
...
```

Now I do want to find a way to execute something like this in a single command. If it can be done only with SQL the better, if not PL/SQL would also do, maybe the PL/SQL could also receive parameters.

Comment: It's not that, one let me put an code example.

Comment: Sounds much the same to me - just `FOR var IN SELECT ... LOOP` over the rows produced by your SQL and `EXECUTE` each row. There's absolutely no way to do this without PL/PgSQL's `EXECUTE`, going via the client, or using some other PL. You'll need a PL/PgSQL function or DO block.

Comment: If you really *must* avoid plpgpsql, the only way is to pipe the script throught psql. (or build an embedded-SQL program which basically juist does the same) The advantage of piping through psql is that you can inspect the output. (and the input script before/after submitting it)